# Where is the right place to put my router?

Tags: apache, tcp, server, router, switching

I have a project and I need to make a building plan with server room etc, so I need to know where to place my router and what do I need to put in my server room besides My servers. 
In the image below i placed my Router in my server room but I don't know if that's right[image: Building Plan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system is a wired system then the position of the router is not really important.

But if it is a wireless, the problem become very very very complicated. I have witness the failure of my university trying to solve your problem (i am a victim). If you want to cover your place with WiFi signal then position of WiFi router must be calculated carefully with the involving of physics otherwise you may encounter issues like signal interference, lag, lost signals and so on.